# How to silence Xcode 64bit/32bit warnings, or better, fix them?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, macros

Code:

```
#define ASSERT_INDEX_IS_WITHIN_BOUNDS(idx,array)
    NSAssert2(idx >= 0 && idx <= (self.array.count-1), @"index %d beyond bounds [0 .. %d]", idx, (self.array.count-1))
```

The above macro causes the following warning:

> Values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead.

This is in third party code and there are **LOADS** of these. How do I silence/fix them?

Comment: build only for 32-bit?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Targeting iPhone 5S.

Comment: in the long run, it is always better to get them to be fixed ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan - But even if we can find "them", is that legal?  Would "they" include Kernighan and Ritchie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still run the app on an iPhone 5S building it for 32-bit only, because the iPhone 5S will run existing 32-bit apps. Many apps will need to wait to start building for 64-bit until library vendors update their code to fix 64-bit issues, and in the case of static libraries to even include a 64-bit build of their code.

There's not really any reason you would absolutely need your code to run in 64-bit right now that I can see, and even if you did, you couldn't guarantee the stability of the third party libraries you're using. So I would suggest you, for the time being, stick with building 32-bit only, and it will run just fine on an iPhone 5S.

If you for some reason did absolutely need to be able to build your app for 64-bit, you'll either have to get the library vendor to update their code, or you'll have to remove it and write your own code to handle what theirs was doing.

EDIT:

To fix this exact warning, in the spots where it has `%d`, replace them with `%lu`.

Comment: I have already switched to 32bit :P But I'm still curious as to how this could be fixed, as it's just a warning.

Comment: Warnings can be serious issues. Just because it still lets you compile it doesn't mean it would run correctly, or at all. In fact even code without any warnings can still fail to work. As for what the warning is complaining about, in this particular case it appears to simply be from the format string being used. But if it's a third party's code, you probably want them to fix it, otherwise you'll have a big mess if you make the changes and later want to use an updated version of it while retaining some of your changes.

Comment: That is talking about warnings and coding practices in general. I would just like to know if this particular warning can be fixed/silenced permanently.

Comment: There would be a compiler flag that would silence it, but it would silence other warnings in your own code that might make it hard to see other real issues. The warning could be blocked just in that one spot, but would require editing that file. It could also be fixed, but again, would involve editing that file.

Comment: Okay. So… how would I go about fixing it, if, hypothetically speaking, I were to go to each warning and fix it?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the solution. Please accept it if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using NSInteger/NSUInteger may solve your implicit conversion warnings.

I had been using int/long types in my code. If you need to support both 32bit and 64bit processors, this is one way to resolve this

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
    typedef long NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
    typedef int NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

As you can see from the NSObjCRuntime.h it converts the NS types to unsigned/signed int/long based on the LP64 (64bit) flag

hope that helps.